# Compare two vectors in R and save result to new vector

Tags: r

I need to compare two vectors in R like:

```
A
[1,2,2,2,2,3]

B
[2,3,4,1,1,1]
```

They both have the same length so i need to compare A with B and find the maximum value and save it to a new vector C, in this case it would be:

```
C
[2,3,4,2,2,3]
```

how can i do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> C <- ifelse(A>B, A, B)
> C
[1] 2 3 4 2 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
will accept your answer in a few minutes

Comment: @Matthew Plourde's answer is better than mine, should accept that one ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is what `pmax` (parallel max) is for:

```
A <- c(1,2,2,2,2,3)
B <- c(2,3,4,1,1,1)
C <- pmax(A, B)
# [1] 2 3 4 2 2 3
```

If your vectors are in a `list` or `data.frame`, you can use `do.call` to pass the list to `pmax`.

```
l <- list(A, B)
do.call(pmax, l)
```